# make kernel select a different IP-adress as its source

Tags: linux, routing

I'm running an ubuntu router using quagga. The router has many virtual interfaces each connected to a different upstream partner. One of these virtual interfaces is connected to an IX. The IP assigned from the IX is not routed globally and is only used to communicate with the peering partners of this IX (it's a public IP however, not a private one).

The problem is that prorgrams running on the router seem to get their source IP depending on the destination IP. So for example `mtr 50.31.164.145` uses our IX assigned IP as its source and thus doesn't work. I know I can specify the source IP when using mtr with `mtr --address X.X.X.X 50.31.164.145`, but there are many programs which don't offer this option.

Is there any way to generally deny the (automatic) usage of an interface/ip, so that the IX assigned IP will never be used automatically?

Comment: using iptables, you can drop packets using the IX assigned IP, however, what you are REALLY asking is how to make the kernel select a different IP-adress as its source. You should edit your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try iptables with SNAT target to change, source IP to another IP when packet is leaving the system with this interface IP address.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.20.20.20 -j SNAT --to-source 10.30.30.30
```

Comment: Thanks, I know and it works...but it looks a bit like a hack to me. So I was wondering if there's another way.